# Aviarc workflows not executing

Tags: aviarc

I have an Aviarc application with a MySQL database.

The main functions of the system are accessed via a main screen with buttons which call different workflows. I added a login form which checks credentials against an authority. This was working. After several unrelated small changes, I have encountered the following problems:

- none of the buttons in the application work (the browser tells me
  they all link to javascript:void(0)
- when I go to a workflow directly (type in url), the called form opens, but without data in it

I have tried the following:

- removed the authentication
- start up a new instance of the application
- tested database connectivity (test query works)

It looks as if none of the workflows execute properly. I'm only at beginner level, so any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Are you able to look into browser's console? Say if you load the application in Chrome, hit F12 and then select Console tab. Do you get any errors logged there?

Comment: Just to expand a bit - buttons having link to "javascript:void(0)" is expected behavior since Aviarc does actions management internally.

When none of the widgets working on the screen(s) its usually due to some Javascript error which could be raised by widget/screen behaviors etc.

Comment: The console view gives me: Uncaught Error: Widget ID 'scn_admin_start:a078dc971f65:users' already exists in map

Comment: This is an indication that you have 2 widgets on the same screen with the same name. Check your screen code and identify what widgets have name "users" and rename one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I found the double up with the widget name on my subscreen. I promise to consult the console in future, before asking for help here.

Comment: @fenix Could you please add that information to the question itself to clarify it? That way Vlad can provide an answer in the appropriate place rather than as a comment. Thanks.